# Use i18n internationalization and Custom Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I want use i18n internationalization. CRUD its works fine, but with custom routes something wrong. How can I use :local in custum routes like this:

```
match 'signup' => 'newsletter#signup'
```

if I use /en/signup it is works, but /signup says: no route match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to use the **i18n_routing** gem?

https://github.com/kwi/i18n_routing

It's easy to translate also the name of the action.